# Find clang::Type in Clang AST by name

Tags: clang, clang++, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api, libclang

In Clang AST, is it possible to find type by name?

For example I have qualified name : `nspace::my_type<int, 10u>`. How can I check if type is present in current translation unit?

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: my knowledge is extremely limited from just once writing a clang tidy check to do some update I needed. Might be wrong.*

There are two possible things that you might need in clang AST depending on the task at hand: `Type` and `TypeLocation`. I needed the type location, so this is what I'll mention first.

### Find the type spelling.

In this case what you actually want is the `TypeLocation` ast nodes. They represent a spelling of a type.
Unfortunately are not printed by clang-query.

The way to search for them is by using a `type_loc` matcher.

This is from something I needed: find all specialisations of a `wide` template.
This would find me all the spellings of `wide<T>`

```
l isWide            hasDeclaration(classTemplateDecl(namedDecl(hasName("wide"))))
l isWideSpec        templateSpecializationType(isWide)
l wideLoc           typeLoc(loc(isWideSpec))
```

`wideLoc` - is what I was using to change the spelling of the type.

Different `type_loc` have parents that are also `type_loc`.

So for example I can find all entries of `T` unless they are inside `wide<T>`

```
typeLoc(loc(asString("T")), unless(hasAncestor(wideLoc)))
```

### Find all of the actual usages of the type, regardless of how it is spelled.

Now for this type of problem you'd need to match on a type.

Have never done this myself, but we can see abseil doing this for example here:
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/b426b45d101740a21610205ec80610c6d0969966/clang-tools-extra/clang-tidy/abseil/UpgradeDurationConversionsCheck.cpp#L36

**PS**. Just in case - all clang ast matchers:
https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersReference.html